# Schedule Apex to Update Leads based on Tasks

Tags: apex, soql, scheduled-apex

**Problem:**

I have two fields on my lead object that I need to back fill information into.

These fields are filled by looking through each of tasks off the lead;
grabbing date/times off these records that match certain conditionals.

Then updating the lead fields based on the earliest time found.

I have created a class to do this, but I am looking to prefect it for learning before running it. there is 22,000+ leads with an average of 10 tasks each.

**Ask:**

Should I Write my SOQL differently? Here is an abridged version

```
Global class populateBackDatedCallReportingFields implements Schedulable {

Global static void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {

    list<Lead> leadList = new list<Lead>();


    //22,798 total leads x 10ish tasks 


    leadList = [SELECT id,
                       (SELECT id,qbdialer__Call_Date_Time__c,CallDisposition FROM Tasks)
                       FROM Lead 
                       WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_90_DAYS];

    if(leadList.size() > 0)
    {

        for( lead l : leadList) {

            for(task t : l.tasks) {
                //find the date/times located on task that meet the requirements

                }
            }

        }

        update leadlist;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should absolutely move this logic into a batch. If you need to update all 22k records, you will run into governor limits. Note that it is not advisable to include child records via subquery in a query locator, so you should retrieve child `Task` records in your execute method. Not also that you can include an `ORDER BY` clause in your subquery.

```
public class MyBatch implements Scheduleable, Database.Batchable<Lead>
{
    public void execute(ScheduleableContext context)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_90_DAYS
        ]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Lead> records)
    {
        List<Lead> freshRecords = [
            SELECT (SELECT ... FROM Tasks ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC)
            FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :records
        ];
        for (Lead freshRecord : freshRecords)
        {
            // put your logic here
        }
        update freshRecords;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) { }
}
```

---

Note that there is no need to check if your collection is empty before iterating. An empty iteration does nothing and has no cost.

```
if(leadList.size() > 0) // this line is not necessary
{
    for (Lead l : leadList)
    {
    }
}
```